# How in this copy constructors is called?

Tags: c++

I am reading copy constructors for the first time. Here is the link from which I am reading it: `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm`

Now, in their first example, in the output, they have written this:

```
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

I just want to know, how exactly the copy constructor is getting called here? In the `main` function, they have written it as:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line
{
   public:
      int getLength( void );
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor
      ~Line();                     // destructor

   private:
      int *ptr;
};

// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(int len)
{
    cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;
    // allocate memory for the pointer;
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
    ptr = new int;
   *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

Line::~Line(void)
{
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    delete ptr;
}
int Line::getLength( void )
{
    return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj)
{
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( )
{
   Line line(10);

   display(line);

   return 0;
}
```

So, it's just `Line line(10)` which will call the constructor for setting length. Why exactly will the copy constructor be called? Wont' the constructor be called when we pass it an actual object of class `Line`?

Comment: What does `display()` do?

Comment: How is `display` defined? Does it take its argument by value or by reference?

Comment: Oh! I thought it's evident from the attached link. I will write the whole program.

Comment: It might be obvious to me or you but not everyone reading this post will figure it out.

Comment: I am sorry for that, I have edited my original post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `line` by  value to `display`.

When you pass an object to a function by value, a copy of the object is created on the stack. In your case, the `obj` parameter of the `display` function is created calling the copy constructor of the `class Line`.

Comment: Right, so when this happens, won't it just call the function `getlength`? Why exactly will the copy constructor be called? I am sorry for this but I am reading these for the first time.

Comment: The copy constructor is called because when you pass by value, a temporary is *created* (Note the word *created*).  To create the temporary `Line`, it has to be constructed, hence the constructor call.

Comment: Also, in the above code, why exactly they have done, `*obj.ptr`?

Comment: Since `ptr` is a pointer too, therefore to access the value at that particular location, shouldn't it be something like, `*obj.*ptr`?

Comment: @JohnLui In the signature of Line copy constructor, obj is declared to be a reference to a (const) object o type Line. It's not a pointer, but a reference, so you can access its members without the *.

Comment: That's true, so it should be used something like this, `obj.*ptr`? Because, `*ptr` is the actual value that we will have to copy.

Comment: * has lower precedence than ., so *ptr.obj is the same as *(ptr.obj)

Comment: If you want to avoid the copy constructor the object should be passed as reference or pointer: `void display2(Line& obj)` or `void display3(Line* obj)`

Answer (score 1):

When you passed solid object as display(Line) function parameter, copy constructor is called because in C++ arguments are passed by value when you pass solid object. So when you passed Line object into function, copy constructor is called to create object copy from existing one. To avoid copying you need to pass parameters by reference or pointer(smart or normal).

Answer (score 1):

`display` is defined like:

```
void display(Line obj)
```

This is pass by value and not pass by reference. A copy must be made which is why the copy constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `display` is defined like:

```
void display(Line obj)
```

This is a `call-by-value`, and in the case of `call-by-value`the copy of the argument is made, not the actual object is passed. Hence when your function is called `copy constructor`is invoked.
If you want to avoid it, pass parameter by reference or pointer.

Change the definition of `Display` from `void display(Line obj)` to

```
void display(Line *obj)
```

and in `main`change the function call from `display(line);` to `display(&line);`